# How to get Spring controller to accept multiple types of JSON

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc, groovy

I have a Spring REST service (written in Groovy; although that shouldn't matter) that exposes a secured endpoint like so:

```
class AppData {
    String id
    String payload
    String fizzbuzz
}

@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
@ResponseBody AppResponse onAppData(@RequestBody AppData appData) {
    // Does some processing on appData and then saves
    // its 'payload' field to a MongoDB
}
```

And this works perfectly fine when it receives JSON of the following form:

```
{
    "id" : "12345",
    "payload" : "Please save me to a MongoDB",
    "fizzbuzz" : "wakka wakka"
}
```

I'm using Jackson to handle JSON serialization here.

The problem is that I now want the `payload` property to be true JSON, not a String. So I want to be able to send the endpoint something like this:

```
{
    "id" : "12345",
    "payload" : {
        "foo" : 24,
        "bar" : false,
        "whistlefeather" : "Yes of course"
    },
    "fizzbuzz" : "wakka wakka"
}
```

And have the payload properly saved off to MongoDB. But here's the catch:

Lots of different teams (potentially hundreds) are going to be sending this endpoint `AppData`, and all of their payloads are going to look completely different (each team has different payloads they want to send me and have saved in MongoDB). And I don't want to have to write a new endpoint and `AppData` subclass for each new team I onboard (and thus expose this endpoint to).

Is there any way I can:

- Keep my endpoint exactly the way it is; but
- Allow the `AppData#payload` property to accept JSON in any form?

Keeping my code exactly the way it is, if I send a JSON message where the `payload` is also JSON (and isn't a string), Spring just returns a 400 with an empty response body. This is happening because Spring expects `payload` to be a String, but sees that its a JSON object.

Any ideas on what I can do inside the `AppData` class to handle this, or any notions of what the best practice is here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a JsonNode as the type for the payload:

```
public class AppData {
    String id;
    JsonNode payload;
    String fizzbuzz;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public JsonNode getPayload() {
        return payload;
    }

    public void setPayload(JsonNode payload) {
        this.payload = payload;
    }

    public String getFizzbuzz() {
        return fizzbuzz;
    }

    public void setFizzbuzz(String fizzbuzz) {
        this.fizzbuzz = fizzbuzz;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String json = "{\n" +
            "    \"id\" : \"12345\",\n" +
            "    \"payload\" : {\n" +
            "        \"foo\" : 24,\n" +
            "        \"bar\" : false,\n" +
            "        \"whistlefeather\" : \"Yes of course\"\n" +
            "    },\n" +
            "    \"fizzbuzz\" : \"wakka wakka\"\n" +
            "}";

        ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
        AppData appData = om.readValue(json, AppData.class);
        System.out.println("appData ID = " + appData.getId());
        System.out.println("appData fizzbuzz = " + appData.getFizzbuzz());
        System.out.println("appData payload = " + appData.getPayload());

        String json2 = "{\n" +
            "    \"id\" : \"12345\",\n" +
            "    \"payload\" : \"Please save me to a MongoDB\",\n" +
            "    \"fizzbuzz\" : \"wakka wakka\"\n" +
            "}";
        appData = om.readValue(json2, AppData.class);
        System.out.println("appData ID = " + appData.getId());
        System.out.println("appData fizzbuzz = " + appData.getFizzbuzz());
        System.out.println("appData payload = " + appData.getPayload());

    }
}
```

Output:

```
appData ID = 12345
appData fizzbuzz = wakka wakka
appData payload = {"foo":24,"bar":false,"whistlefeather":"Yes of course"}
appData ID = 12345
appData fizzbuzz = wakka wakka
appData payload = "Please save me to a MongoDB"
```

Note that to get back a JSON string for the payload, you shouldn't use toString() as in the above example. You should use `objectMapper.writeValueAsString(payload)`.

Comment: Oh @JB Nizet, as always, you are my hero; thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a Map, i don't know what it is in Groovy, but this would be the structure in Java.

```
public class AppData {
    String id;
    Map<String, Object> payload;
    String fizzbuzz;
}
```