# Can Spring/Jackson to deserialize any XML into a JsonNode?

Tags: xml, spring-mvc, jackson, deserialization

Several months ago I had asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41653116/how-to-get-spring-controller-to-accept-multiple-types-of-json) where essentially I had a Spring `@RestController` accepting JSON payloads of unknown form/structure and I needed a data model to handle it.

The recommended approach was to use a Jackson `JsonNode` as my data model since that would happily deserialize from any valid JSON payload.

I'm now trying to accomplish the same but with XML. Essentially I want the same endpoint to also accept *any* XML and deserialize it into an in-memory object (other than a string). I'm hoping that under the hood Jackson can deserialize both JSON and XML into `JsonNode` instances, but if not, is there an "`XmlNode`" equivalent here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to deserialize both json and xml using jackson framework of spring. Just add the dependency of jackson-dataformat-xml. Find below the reference

https://spring.io/blog/2014/12/02/latest-jackson-integration-improvements-in-spring

Comment: Thanks @M.Navy but thats not what I'm asking here. I know its *possible* to deserialize JSON and XML in Spring! I want my RestController to accept *any* XML as the body/request entity and I want it deserialized to the same object type! I can do that with JSON via `JsonNode` but I'm wondering what the equivalent is for XML.

Comment: So if `<fizz id="123"/>` is the request entity, I want that deserialized to something (again, not a string) that can represent it. And if `<buzz><foo bar="yes"/></buzz>` is sent as the request entity, I want it deserialized to the same exact object type as the first one!

Comment: Do you want to deserialize xml data to a json object or POJO?

Comment: Thanks @M.Navy, I'm fine deserializing into a JSON object (preferably the same `JsonNode` that I'm already using for JSON request entities), but if that's not possible for some reason, I need the XML equivalent of `JsonNode`. But **not** a POJO (that I would define myself).

Comment: Jackson-dataformat-xml library will internally handles xml data to jsonnode conversion. So you can map the request body to jsonnode object. But I have not tried and implemented this.